# Customizing Pandoc's Slidy CSS?

Tags: slideshow, pandoc

I'm using the amazing Pandoc to convert from Markdown to the Slidy slideshow format. I'd like to edit the Slidy CSS but I can't for the life of me figure out where the CSS file is that's getting used. I've found a bunch of slidy.css files here and there and tried modifying them, but Pandoc's Slidy output never changes.

Does anyone know where slidy.css is by default on OSX? Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default pandoc uses the CSS and javascript files from the slidy website.  If you want to use local versions, create a directory, say `myslidy`, with subdirectories `scripts` and `styles`.  Put `slidy.js.gz` in `scripts` and `slidy.css` in `styles`.  Then call pandoc with the following options:

```
pandoc -s -t slidy -V slidy-url=myslidy
```

Pandoc will then link to your local CSS file.  If you'd like to include all of this in the HTML file itself, so it doesn't depend on the external myslidy directory, then add the option `--self-contained`.

Another option is to keep using the slidy script from the slidy website, but substitute your own CSS file.  To do that, you'd have to create a custom slidy template with a different stylesheet link.  To get your own copy of the default template, do

```
pandoc -D slidy > my.slidy
```

Edit the CSS link in this file, and call pandoc with

```
pandoc -s -t slidy --template my.slidy
```

Comment: thanks quick response! Trying to get first method to work.
  
(1) In my home directory (/Users/peter/) I created a folder called "myslidy" and put those subfolders and files in it. So i.e. I now have ~/myslidy/scripts and ~/myslidy/styles with the requisite files inside.  
  
(2) I edited the styles in ~/myslidy/styles/slidy.css.  
  
(3) In Terminal, from my home directory, I call Pandoc:  
  
`$ pandoc -s -t slidy --self-contained -V slidy-url=myslidy -o Desktop/pandoc_output.html slidy-test.md`  
  
But the Slidy output still has default styling! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hm, I just tested the first approach and found what you found.  Looking at the code, I see that the `--self-contained` option sets the `slidy-url` variable to `slidy`.  I think I did that to avoid dependence on a net connection, but it was probably a bad idea.  Anyway, (a) call your directory `slidy` instead of `myslidy` or (b) edit the system default, `/usr/local/share/pandoc-1.9.4.2/slidy/styles/slidy.css`, or create a local default by putting a revised `slidy` directory under `~/.pandoc`.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much, that totally worked! Last question: If I want to create a few different stylesheets to create (self-contained) Slidy presentations for different kinds of situations, where do I put the various CSS files and how do I call one vs. another?

Comment: Two possibilities.  First, you might use the second approach described above, with a custom template.  Change the link to the slidy CSS from `$slidy-url$/styles/slidy.css` to `$slidy-css-url$`.  Then invoke pandoc with `pandoc -s -t slidy --template my.slidy -V slidy-css-url /path/to/custom-slidy-css.css`.  Or you could hardcode the path in the template and use multiple templates.  A simpler idea: If your css customizations are not extreme, you might try simply overriding aspects of the default slidy CSS with another CSS file included using the `--css` option.

Answer (score 10):

Specify additional css files with `pandoc -t slidy --css my.css ...`.
This doesn't require modifying pandoc's default slidy templates.

(This is in John MacFarlane's earlier comment. I'm just posting it as an
answer for higher visibility.)